# How to make payment to 2 stripe connected accounts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have an app, that should make a payment to 2 connected accounts
[image]
I can do a payment only separate for those 2 accounts,

my question is how to make the payment of multiple accounts together

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 999,
  currency: 'usd',
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  payment_method: '{{PAYMENT_METHOD_ID}}',
  customer: '{{CUSTOMER_ID}}',
}, {
  stripeAccount: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',// how to provide here multiple ids
});
```

Comment: Is the intention to create 2 separate Payment Intents, 1 for each connected account?

Comment: yes, exact, for example I have two products in my shopping card but each of them have an Id of connected accounts(you can see in photo), I need  the way that I can do the payment not separated, all together  
@JonathanSteele

Comment: You can't pass multiple account IDs to the `stripeAccount` parameter. You'll need to create a separate Payment Intent for each.

Comment: so there is no another api in stripe that I can realize this idea with, right?
@JonathanSteele

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. If you're trying to create a [direct charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) on 2 separate connected accounts, then you can't do this in a single API call (like you're attempting to). If your intention is to create a single payment, but then split it between 2 separate connected accounts then you should look at [separate charges and transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers).